# I have 4 ViewControllers in a TabBarController. Only 3 are dealloc'd when the TabBarController is dealloc'd. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, dealloc

I have a custom UITabBarController. I'm logging the 4 ViewControllers that are used with it, and I am getting what I expect.

However, when I tap the back button in the NavigationController, which removes the custom UITabBarController, only 3 of the 4 VC's have their dealloc method called. Why might this be?

```
2016-03-11 14:46:06.966 [24357:9827962] -[CustomTabBarController dealloc]
2016-03-11 14:46:06.967 [24357:9827962] -[FourthViewController dealloc]
2016-03-11 14:46:06.967 [24357:9827962] -[SecondViewController dealloc]
2016-03-11 14:46:06.968 [24357:9827962] -[FirstViewController dealloc]
```

ThirdViewController is never dealloc'd. I have a log statement there, but cannot figure out why this might not be dealloc'd like the rest. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have a retain cycle somewhere

Comment: As dan has said, make sure that `ThirdViewController` is not hold by any other object. It will help me tell if I can see your code.

Comment: @dan Yup, there was. I had a block on the heap pointing back to self, and when the TabBarController was deallocd, ThirdViewController was still being pointed to by this block.

Answer (score 1):

can you please post your code...As per other suggestions, it does seem that they may be a strong reference somewhere which is not letting your viewcontroller release.